# ubuntu: How to zip a directory in ubuntu by excluding some subdirectories from command line

Tags: ubuntu, zip

I want to zip a directory by excluding some unwanted subdirectories. I have tried :

```
zip -r test.zip * -x 'test1/' 'test2/'
```

and

```
zip -r test.zip * -x 'test1/' -x 'test2/'
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: ported to [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1296201/ubuntu-how-to-zip-a-directory-in-ubuntu-by-excluding-some-subdirectories-from-c/1296202#1296202) in case the question remains closed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
zip -r test.zip * -x test1/\* test2/\*
```

The `\*` is an escaped wildcard character, which avoids path expansion by the shell prior to being passed to `zip`.

Comment: Worked like a charm !! Thanks